# How to send int to arduino with Python

Tags: python, arduino

I was trying to control a Servo with Python but I have only Arduino to control a Servo. I was found how to control servo with writing numbers but I can't send int to arduino.I was trying to send this

```
first = 680/ a
last = 180/ first
```

I was trying to send 'last' but I can't do it. Please help me and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: http://www.handsontec.com/dataspecs/L298N%20Motor%20Driver.pdf

Comment: you can achieve this py using serial communication between pythong arduino. Here is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKGYbMD3NT8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that connects to an Arduino and sends it data:

```
import serial
port = serial.Serial("/path/to/your/arduino/port", 9600)
port.write(bytes("180", "utf-8")) # This is just an example; you can use any string

# Close the port when you're done talking to the Arduino
port.close()
```

Notice that you need to convert the string to `bytes` before sending it, and that you need to specify the encoding. Just use whatever encoding your program uses. Here, it's UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for writing this. I want to make a camera stand for an algorithm that identifies objects in an image, this camera stand needs to track SPECIAL objects in the image by bringing them right in the middle of the camera image. I can get the exact midpoint positions of the defined object, but I cannot send it to the arduino with pyserial because it is a variable and I need to divide the defined object's positions by X coordinate 680 and then 180 so that I can turn the servo into right angles. I need to do the same operation in Y coordinate, but this time I need to divide by 480 and then 180.

Comment: @testy: You *can* send variables to the Arduino using `pyserial`. Just give the variable as the argument to `port.write()`. If the variable is not a string, you may want to use `port.write(str(variable))`.

Comment: Doesn't work. error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\halil\sil\sill.py", line 8, in <module>
    ser.write(str(a))
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 310, in write
    data = to_bytes(data)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 65, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: {!r}'.format(seq))
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '320'

Comment: I defined a = 310 + 10 to example but it gives error. If i use only variable it doesn't give any error but this time the data I send it goes 0.

Comment: @testy: My mistake. I should have put `port.write(bytes(str(variable), "utf-8"))`. If that doesn't work, try using different encodings instead of `"utf-8"`. This worked on my computer.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. if I get any problems to making this project can I ask you?

Comment: @testy: Just post questions when you have them, and I'll keep an eye out for them :-)! Please consider accepting my answer if it's what you needed; that way, other users will know the question has been satisfactorily answered.

Comment: I have a few problems and how can I reach you. Do you use Discord or something like that?

Comment: @testy: Unfortunately, I have very little experience with web-request related things. Sorry 'bout that! You can check my Developer Story for the things I do work with.

Comment: This doesn't mean you shoudn't post a question when you have one.